# Access denied when enabling or setting by default a theme (on Nginx)

Tags: installation

I get an *Access denied* error page when attempting to **enable** or **set by default** a theme. It is kinda weird as I am allowed to perform other admin tasks.

I checked that my user is an administrator and it has all the permissions granted. I also made other checkings that I found in Drupal's forums and Drupal Answers but everything seems to be OK.

I have a *standard* install with no additional modules. Watchdog logs show the access denied warnings from `http://drupal-testing/admin/appearance/enable?token=<...>&theme=encoreweb`. In addition to check the permissions of my user, I reviewed `settings.php` to verify `$cookie_domain` was commented.

I've found that [I'm not the only one with this problem](https://drupal.org/node/1134686), but I couldn't come to a conclusion.

Comment: Is it a clean install? Or what modules you are using? What's in watchdog? *"I also made other checkings"* - which ones?

Comment: @Mołot I just edited my question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a solution after several hours working on it.

I am using **Nginx** instead of Apache and I did not configure it to add the query string in the rewriting to `index.php`. So neither the `token` nor the `theme` parameters were reaching the script and `system_theme_enable()`/`system_theme_default()` (located in `/modules/system/system.admin.inc`) always returned `MENU_ACCESS_DENIED`, which I consider to be a very confusing behavior by the way.

This is how the server config looks like now and makes it work:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: This affected various operations involving a query string for me - everything from performing a search, to clearing the cache. It threw a non-specific 404 (missing token), so was hard to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this question my specific scenario. I had installed Drupal 8.0.3 on Debian 8 (jessie), with php5-fpm and nginx. The install seemed to go flawlessly, until I tried to add a theme. I got "Access Denied" when attempting to set default theme from the administration page.

I had followed [some](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-up-nginx-php-fpm-and-mariadb-on-debian-8) guides for NGINX/Drupal installs, and wound up with the following section in my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Per [this answer](https://www.drupal.org/node/1114770) on drupal.org, the `$args` parameter worked for me, updating the section to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```